# Unit test terms

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, terminology

Colleagues of mine are calling a class with test methods a fixture, but I think that is wrong because a "fixture" is a fixed environment for testing.

[NUnit uses the (wrong?) term "TestFixture"](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testFixture&r=2.5) too.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_fixture#Test_fixture_in_xUnit) says:

> In generic xUnit, a test fixture is
>   all the things that must be in place
>   in order to run a test and expect a
>   particular outcome.
>
> Frequently fixtures are created by
>   handling setUp() and tearDown() events
>   of the unit testing framework. In
>   setUp() one would create the expected
>   state for the test, and in tearDown()
>   it would clean up what had been set
>   up.

So I would call setup and teardown fixtures but not the whole class. Is that correct?

And how to call the class with the test cases? A "test suite" following the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html)?

Comment: You are definitely right about the fixture thing and I would also agree on the "test suite".

Comment: I would second the fixture terminology but a test suite for me is a group of testcases. This **could** be one class but is usually spread out over multiple classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **test case** is a **single test** testing a particular thing.

A **test suite** is a **grouping of test cases** into a set of tests that for some reason "belong together".

A **test fixture** manages (setup/teardown) the **state before and after a test case** is being executed.

These are concepts and **how these are implemented depends on the test framework**.

E.g. a test case can be a function or a class; a test suite might be a class containing test cases as functions or just a container with test cases (this again can be implemented in various ways); a test fixture might be built-in into the test framework as e.g. dedicated functions, or it might just be a fixture class taking care of the state through its construction and destruction.

**Edit**

One thing I believe is important is to use the terminology of the test framework and follow the recommended approach of the test framework (if such exists). A lot of confusion comes through not naming things consistently and similarly. This is true for everything.